# Accessing Ansible Inventory

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am trying to model different environments (local, development, sandbox) under two regions. For each environment, I have defined properties for that environment (such as `rest_api_port: '8080'`) that I need to refer to in my playbook.

Given the below, how can I run my Ansible playbook against the local environment only in ewest?

I have tried the following but it seems like it tries to run against all hosts in `euwest`:

`ansible-playbook playbook.yaml --inventory inventory.yaml --limit="euwest:local"`

```
---
euwest:
  hosts:
    local:
      ansible_connection: local
      rest_api_host: 127.0.0.1
      rest_api_password: "{{ lookup('env', 'REST_API_PASSWORD') }}"
      rest_api_port: '8080'
      rest_api_timeout: '60'
      rest_api_username: admin
    development:
      ansible_connection: local
      rest_api_host: dev.messaging.cloud
      rest_api_password: "{{ lookup('env', 'REST_API_PASSWORD') }}"
      rest_api_port: '943'
      rest_api_timeout: '60'
      rest_api_username: dev-admin
    sandbox:
      ansible_connection: local
      rest_api_host: sand.messaging.cloud
      rest_api_password: "{{ lookup('env', 'REST_API_PASSWORD') }}"
      rest_api_port: '9443'
      rest_api_timeout: '60'
      rest_api_username: sand-admin
apsouth:
  hosts:
    local:
      ansible_connection: local
      rest_api_host: 127.0.0.1
      rest_api_password: "{{ lookup('env', 'REST_API_PASSWORD') }}"
      rest_api_port: '8081'
      rest_api_timeout: '60'
      rest_api_username: admin
    development:
      ansible_connection: local
      rest_api_host: dev2.messaging.cloud
      rest_api_password: "{{ lookup('env', 'REST_API_PASSWORD') }}"
      rest_api_port: '9091'
      rest_api_timeout: '60'
      rest_api_username: dev-admin
    sandbox:
      ansible_connection: local
      rest_api_host: sand2.messaging.cloud
      rest_api_password: "{{ lookup('env', 'REST_API_PASSWORD') }}"
      rest_api_port: '443'
      rest_api_timeout: '60'
      rest_api_username: sand-admin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A host in Ansible is identified only by name. If you list the same hostname in multiple groups, you still only have a single host: it's just a member of multiple groups.

That is, if I have:

```
euwest:
  hosts:
    development:
apsouth:
  hosts:
    development:
```

Then I have just put the single host `development` in two hostgroups (`euwest` and `apsouth`).

---

For what you're trying to do, your best option is probably to use multiple inventory files. Create `euwest.yaml` with:

```
all:
  hosts:
    local:
      ansible_connection: local
      rest_api_host: 127.0.0.1
      rest_api_password: "{{ lookup('env', 'REST_API_PASSWORD') }}"
      rest_api_port: '8080'
      rest_api_timeout: '60'
      rest_api_username: admin
    development:
      ansible_connection: local
      rest_api_host: dev.messaging.cloud
      rest_api_password: "{{ lookup('env', 'REST_API_PASSWORD') }}"
      rest_api_port: '943'
      rest_api_timeout: '60'
      rest_api_username: dev-admin
    sandbox:
      ansible_connection: local
      rest_api_host: sand.messaging.cloud
      rest_api_password: "{{ lookup('env', 'REST_API_PASSWORD') }}"
      rest_api_port: '9443'
      rest_api_timeout: '60'
      rest_api_username: sand-admin
```

And `apsouth.yaml` with:

```
all:
  hosts:
    local:
      ansible_connection: local
      rest_api_host: 127.0.0.1
      rest_api_password: "{{ lookup('env', 'REST_API_PASSWORD') }}"
      rest_api_port: '8081'
      rest_api_timeout: '60'
      rest_api_username: admin
    development:
      ansible_connection: local
      rest_api_host: dev2.messaging.cloud
      rest_api_password: "{{ lookup('env', 'REST_API_PASSWORD') }}"
      rest_api_port: '9091'
      rest_api_timeout: '60'
      rest_api_username: dev-admin
    sandbox:
      ansible_connection: local
      rest_api_host: sand2.messaging.cloud
      rest_api_password: "{{ lookup('env', 'REST_API_PASSWORD') }}"
      rest_api_port: '443'
      rest_api_timeout: '60'
      rest_api_username: sand-admin
```

And then pick which one to use at runtime with the `-i` option:

```
ansible-playbook -i apsouth.yaml playbook.yaml
```

---

> If I need to restrict the playbook to only run against local in euwest, can I just pass --limit="local" ?

Sure. The `--limit` option limits execution to a specific host or group. Nothing we've done here changes that behavior.

> Will the properties of each host be seamlessly available to me in my playbook role? E.g. In my playbook, host: "{{ rest_api_host }}"

Also yes :). Again, nothing we've done here changes the behavior; the only difference is that now we have two inventory files, so each host is part of only a single hostgroup rather than being part of two host groups.

Comment: Ok amazing thank you. Two more questions please;

1. If I need to restrict the playbook to only run against `local` in `euwest`, can I just pass `--limit="local"` ?


2. Will the properties of each host be seamlessly available to me in my playbook role? E.g. In my playbook, `host: "{{ rest_api_host }}"`

Comment: I've updated the answer in response to your questions.

Comment: Thank you so much. You're right on the above of course. I am using an Ansible Module in my playbook that expected the host entry to be `localhost` and not `local`. Hence the confusion on my part and the additional two questions.